# Nginx worker process this many is normal?

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I have EC2 m4.2xlarge running Nginx 1.6.1 and serving static HTML files. Recently my server started to give 503 server temporary unavailable. When I check the server process the CPU was all 100% load. Is this mean I am lacking server power or my nginx.conf configuration is not set right.

I have this in the conf currently.

```
worker_processes  8;

worker_rlimit_nofile 12288;
events {
    worker_connections  6096;
    multi_accept on;
    use epoll;
}
```

In my Google Analytics realtime access I have about 700~800 users which is isn't  many comparing during the day. So I don't think its due to high traffic.

[image: Screenshot of htop]

Comment: Do the logs show anything suspicious? Try enabling the nginx status page to get more data on what's going on: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/nginx-enable-and-see-current-status-page/

Comment: @Bazze unfortunately HttpStubStatusModule is not compiled with this server.

Comment: Have you reloaded nginx's configuration? Do you have long connection (like web sockets)?

Comment: Do you cache the responses in memory? Or are you accessing the file system on each request?

Comment: @AlexeyTen Yes i have reload. How do I check for long connection?

Comment: @Bazze I have PageSpeed Module installed but other than that I think each file is going through the file system.

Comment: Alright. If you are just serving static files you should definitely enable caching for everything, there is no need for visiting the file system on each request. Try a web search for "nginx cache static files" and you'll find a lot of information on how to do it.

Comment: @Bazze Nginx cache looks complicated so I will try with Pagespeed moduile memchache mode.

Comment: You have long request. See http://nginx.org/en/docs/control.html#reconfiguration how reload works. I guess, you also should look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/32497801/1016033

Comment: @AlexeyTen I have not set proxy_read_timeout manually so it should of default 60s

Comment: @Maca it's 60sec between two reads. If your server sends pings then it could have this connect indefinitely.

Comment: @AlexeyTen Ok. I have been doing some searches and came up with proxy_read_timeout 180s; is what I should set. I will try this out.